# JS extracting specific strings from array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
function extractLinks(input) {
    var html = input.join('\n');
    var regex = /<a\s+([^>]+\s+)?href\s*=\s*('([^']*)'|"([^"]*)|([^\s>]+))[^>]*>/g;
    var match;
    while (match = regex.exec(html)) {
        var hrefValue = match[3];
        if (hrefValue == undefined) {
            var hrefValue = match[4];
        }
        if (hrefValue == undefined) {
            var hrefValue = match[5];
        }
        console.log(hrefValue);
    }
}
```

By all means, this is a simple function, that extracts all **href values**, but only these, which are real hrefs, e.g. href that is defined as `class="href"`, or outside A tag, etc. are not included.
The thing that is weird about all this, is that the `regex` I created for this calculation is 
**`(<a[\s\S]*?>)`**
but when I didn't manage to find a solution, and looked at the original one, I found this very long `regex`.
Tried this solution with my `regex`, it won't work.

Can please, someone explain, how can I interpret this long `regex`.
And then, match returns an array, well.
Let me see If I get the idea of this while loop:

> while ( match = the regex is present in the string) {
>       something = match[3] */* why 3???*/*
>       and then if undefined something = match[4],
>       if undefined again something = match[5];
>   }

I do really struggle to understand the mechanism behind all of this, as well as the logic in the `regex`.

The input is generated by a system, which will parse 10 different arrays of strings, but lets take one, which I use to test:
The code below is parsed as array of strings with length as the lines, every line is a separate element in the array, and this is the argument input for the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hyperlinks</title>
  <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<ul><li><a   href="/"  id="home">Home</a></li><li><a
 class="selected" href=/courses>Courses</a>
</li><li><a href = 
'/forum' >Forum</a></li><li><a class="href"
onclick="go()" href= "#">Forum</a></li>
<li><a id="js" href =
"javascript:alert('hi yo')" class="new">click</a></li>
<li><a id='nakov' href =
http://www.nakov.com class='new'>nak</a></li></ul>
<a href="#empty"></a>
<a id="href">href='fake'<img src='http://abv.bg/i.gif' 
alt='abv'/></a><a href="#">&lt;a href='hello'&gt;</a>
<!-- This code is commented:
  <a href="#commented">commentex hyperlink</a> -->
</body>
```

Comment: [**ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes **](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an understanding of what this regex is doing, I have put inline comments in [this page](http://regex101.com/r/qQ3nA9/1) that you can review. I'm also copying it here:

```
<a\s+            # Look for '<a' followed by whitespace
([^>]+\s+)?      # Look for anything else that isn't 'href='
                 # such as 'class=' or 'id='
href\s*=\s*      # locate the 'href=' with any whitespace around the '=' character
(
  '([^']*)'      # Look for '...'
|                # ...or...
  "([^"]*)       # Look for "..."
|                # ...or...
  ([^\s>]+)      # Look anything NOT '>' or spaces
)
[^>]*>           # Match anything else up to the closing '>'
```

This is just to break it apart so you can see what each of these portions are doing. As far as your questions about the `match`, I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: Well, thanks for the regex, will have a look.
And the part 'bout the while loop is, why we take the third element of the array match, and if it is undefined we go for the 4th, then 5th.

Comment: I think what is happening here is that there are parts of the URL that are being "captured" that aren't necessary to be kept. [This one](http://regex101.com/r/qQ3nA9/3) has a few changes where it ONLY captures the `href=` portion. In that case, you can see the replacement at the bottom of that page.

Comment: You sir, have my gratitude.